# NetSuite Sandbox SOAP WSDL Inaccessible

Tags: netsuite

I'm attempting to connect a client website to their NetSuite using

- SOAP
- Token Based Authentication
- NetSuite PHP API Client (https://github.com/netsuitephp/netsuite-php)

To start, I have access to their Sandbox.

Originally I was getting an "Invalid login attempt." before stumbling upon the different sandbox URL.

Wrong: https://webservices.netsuite.com
Worked: https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com

This got me past the invalid login, but now I'm getting

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2022_1_0/netsuite.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2022_1_0/netsuite.wsdl"
```

I cannot access https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2022_1_0/netsuite.wsdl in a browser. However, I *can* access https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2022_1_0/netsuite.wsdl.

What am I missing? Should the WSDL be available in Sandbox? Should I be connecting to Sandbox in a different way?

I tried connecting to NetSuite Sandbox via SOAP. I expected to connect successfully and complete a simple test request (getting a Customer by Internal ID).

Comment: If you are sure that this exact url works in production, then it looks like it's a permission issue in SB.

Answer (score 0):

Your url doesn't look like correct.
You need to use the url that you can find under "Setup>Company>Company information" Tab "Company URLs" Field "SUITETALK (SOAP AND REST WEB SERVICES)"
It will look like this: https://{{company-id}}.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com
Don't forget to create an integration with Client id and Client secret.
Link this integration to a role to get the token id and token secret.
To use the WSDL, you need to add it in the header